# What does this for loop do in C ?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, conditional-statements

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {    
    int i= 1, j = 1;
    for (; j; printf("%d  %d",i, j))
        j = i++ <= 5;
    return 0;
}
```

**output-**

```
2  13  14  15  16  17  0
```

Can anyone explain what is happening inside the loop? This question was asked in the interview process.

Comment: *"This question is asked by Zoho Cooperation in the interview process"* - To be frank, if you need help answering it, you better find a good source of learning C in a structured manner. Asking for a crash course about *this code* from strangers on SO won't make you a good candidate to pass the interview. They'll just weed you out with something else, possibly harder.

Comment: See this link : https://wandbox.org/permlink/kusAhEDsuivV8O0N

Comment: Oh, and if that's what they use to screen candidates, you don't want to work there.

Comment: @StoryTeller Well it is pretty clever to use questions like these during interview to weed out the quacks. I'd like to include a question about `i=i++;` during interviews, just to tell if the candidate knows that such code is fishy, or at least provoke a reaction "who would write such crap code". Anyone who starts to ponder the inner workings of `i=++` instead of questioning the specification, is a code monkey, not an engineer. Though of course if a company uses questions about obfuscated code and actually expect you to tell what it does, then that's a bad company indeed.

Comment: @Lundin - I agree with you on all counts. And that's the beauty of it. You can weed out the quacks with a single statement. No need for monstrosities like this. Proves that both the company and the candidate are worth their salt.

Comment: There's a proposal in C++ to define the behaviour of `i=i++;` I hope all interviewers are well-versed on that.

Comment: @Bathsheba The order of evaluation of the = operator was already specified in C++11 (unlike C11). And since the two operands of the = are therefore sequenced, I believe that code is well-defined from C++11 and beyond?

Comment: I don't think it is, but this is the kind of thing that @StoryTeller knows. Methinks it's C++20.

Comment: It isn't well defined prior to C++17. A single sentence, *"The right operand is sequenced before the left operand."*, is present in [C++17](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.ass#1) and absent in [C++14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.ass#1)

Comment: Uh right, it isn't well-defined but I believe `i=++i;` is. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points/4183735#4183735

Comment: Yeah, pre-increment was on surer footing since C++11. Another interesting thing to poke candidates with

Answer (score 3):

The code is equivalent to:

```
int main(void) {    
  int i=1,j=1;
  while (j != 0) {
    j = (i<=5);
    i = i+1;
    printf("%d  %d",i,j);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I think that its meaning and the output is evident now. Note that `printf` does not print any separator after the second number. It means that the two digit "numbers" in the output are printed by two successive invocations of `printf` each. If you use `printf("%d  %d;  ",i,j);` instead of `printf("%d  %d",i,j);` the output will be:

```
2  1;  3  1;  4  1;  5  1;  6  1;  7  0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is the same as

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i = 1, j = 1;

    while (j > 0) {
        if (i <= 5) {
            j = 1;
        } else {
            j = 0; 
        }

        i = i + 1;
        printf("%d  %d",i, j);
    }
}
```

It should now be easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, `i` and `j` are `1` so condition for loop will be true and it will enter into the loop.
At `j = i++<=5;` statement first it will execute conditional operation and assign result of conditional operation (true = 1, or, false = 0) to `j` and increment `i` by one. After this, it will execute print statement from the loop which will print value for `i` (which is now incremented by one is 2) and `j` (will be 1 as the condition is true). This will continue until the `i<=5` condition is true. Whenever `i` becomes greater than 5 `j` will be 0, breaking the loop.

Answer (score 0):

De-obfuscated, the code is equivalent to this:

```
for(int i=1; i<7; i++)
{
  printf("%d\t%d\n", i+1, (i+1) < 7);
}
```

What such a loop would be needed for, I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

To make the code and its output more clear rewrite the program the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    for ( int i = 1, j = 1; j != 0; )
    {
        j = i++ <= 5;
        printf("%d  %d\n", i, j );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
2  1
3  1
4  1
5  1
6  1
7  0
```

As the variable `j` is calculated as a result of this condtion

```
i++ <= 5
```

then it will be always equal to `1` except when `i` will be equal to `6` because for this value of `i` the condition is evaluted to false that is to `0` and this value is assigned to `j`.

So the last iteration of the loop is when `i` is equal to 6. In this case after this statement

```
j = i++ <= 5;
```

i will be equal to `7` and j will be equal to `0`. These values are outputted in the last iteration of the loop.

```
7  0
```